# Can physically see CSS changes occur when refreshing page

Tags: css

My theme has some built-in options in customize to change things like base font weight and font type, but for font color I add a bit of css to the themes custom css option it also offers.

I notice that regardless of whether I apply css font changes by adding them to custom css or using the themes built in options, this problem remains.

The problem is when I refresh the page I can physically see the css changes take effect. I will see the font used for my content quickly change in font weight and color, from the themes default to what I customized it to. This will occur in about half a second. And it makes the site look less than professional.

Is there a way for the custom css to apply the changes instantly upon refresh?

Comment: This isn't anything to do with WordPress itself, it has to do with however your theme handles customisation. You need to speak to the theme author.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a plugin that adds the css to the cache, disable it and try again.

However, chances are that it's caused by the way your browser handles the cache and most browsers will keep the css in the cache. Therefore, the problem would be unique to your computer and browser. Make sure your browser is up to date, and try a different browser or a different computer to see if the issue is universal.